# Displaying data from two combined tables according to third table row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, html-table

I am extremely new to PHP and MYSQL. I know I should be using MYSQLI, but I do not have that option in this case, so please bear with me!

I have three tables in my MYSQL database that looks as follows:

**Table A**
UserID | Topic | Date | rating

**Table B**
UserID | Username | User email

**Table C**
Topic | Description

Then I have my PHP page with a table displaying the information in TableA with a 'Details' button in each row.

What I want to do, is that if the Details button is clicked, the combined information for tables B & C are displayed according to the Topic in that row.

eg. The image below illustrates the table on the page, and if you click on the button in the row for Topic 2, the second table appears with a list of all users who selected topic2.

**|Topic|UserID|Date     |Details   |**

|    2    |     01   | 11-11-2012  | *Button here* |

|    3    |     02   | 12-11-2012  | *Button here* |

|    2    |     03   | 11-01-2012  | *Button here* |

|    5    |     04   | 11-08-2012  | *Button here* |

*When the button in the first row is clicked:*

**|  UserID  |  Username  |  Useremail  |  Topics             |**

|   01     |     name01     | usermail 1  | *Topic Description* |

|   03     |    name03     | usermail 3  | *Topic Description* |

My coding for the first table looks like this:

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course ORDER BY cname") or die ("error");

    echo '</br><h4 align="center"> Listing </h4></br>';     
    echo'<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="POST">
<table border="1" width="50%" align="center"> 
<tr>
    <td>
        <h4>Topic</h4>
    </td>
    <td>
        <h4>UserID</h4>
    </td>
    <td>
        <h4>Details</h4>
    </td>
    </tr>';
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
            echo'<tr>
        <td>
                       '.$row['topic'].'
        </td>
        <td>
        <form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">
                     '.$row['Description'].'  
                    </td> 
                    <td>    
                    <align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="list"  value=" button" />
        </form>
        </td>
        </tr>';
    }
```

Please, could anyone help with what I should do next?

I know I am supposed to use joins, but not sure which one or how.
The buttons must somehow know what row they are in, in order to know which topics info must be displayed, but I have no idea how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly understand what you're asking, nor how the tables particularly relate to one another. I'm assuming Table B is the user database table, and Table A is like a topics database table, and I am also assuming Table C to be the comments made to Table A. Is this relationship correct? (I will edit this post as I become more clear on what exactly is going on).

Edit 1: Is this what you're talking about? As I already commented, I don't understand the use of the third table for something like this?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE Topic=10";
$ans = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($ans)){

}

mysql_free_result($ans)
```

Edit 2: To speed this exchange up, I'm going to give you a quick rundown on just about everything I know about joined tables.

There's a few ways to select data from more than 1 table, and you use which method is most suitable for your purposes.

Assume we have the following setup of tables:

```
Users : user_id, username, user_email
Topics: topic_id, user_id, topic_title, topic_text
Posts: post_id, topic_id, user_id, post_text
```

This is a setup from PhpBB, which I deal with quite frequently. The first table is simple enough, it's the user information table, storing everything about the user. The second is a list of Topics posted giving just the basic information of the title and who posted it. The third, which is the important one, are ALL of the posts to the topic other than the original. E.G. a topic with the title "who would win in a fight..." with the text of "Superman or Batman" would simply have "who would win in a fight..." in topic_title and "superman or Batman" in topic_text, whereas the first comment to that thread of "Batman" would be in the posts table.

Now, Assume I'm on my forum board so I want to see ALL of the topics there are to decide where I should post. This is done through

```
$sql = "SELECT t.*,u.username FROM topics t, users u WHERE u.user_id=t.user_id";
$ans = mysql_query($sql);

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($ans)){
     echo $result['topic_title'].' | '.$result['username'].'<br />';
}
```

This is the most basic version of joining tables. It says that i going to select everything from topics, and username from users where the user_id column on the users table is the same as the user_id column in the topics table. There's another way to write this, but for now let's focus on basics.

This will give you results like this

```
Who would win in a fight... | Bob123
If you could go anywhere in the world | Jose567
Where is the most awkward place you've ever sneezed | Sneezerella
```

I didn't put the code in to make the titles clickable, but assuming you know about HTML, that shouldn't be hard. So now assume we've clicked on one of these links, which should look something akin to

```
<a href="viewtopic.php?t=1">Who would win in a fight...</a>
```

So, we are now on viewtopic.php, being passed one parameter, t. We would then take t and go about it like this:

```
//Assuming connections somewhere up here

$sql = "SELECT t.*,u.username FROM topics t, users u WHERE u.user_id=t.topic_id AND t.topic_id=".$_GET['t']; //This should look familiar, also remember to sanitize your MySQL data, don't just tack it on straight from the $_GET variable like I did. I'm typing this while dealing with my 8 month old
$ans = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$first_post = mysql_fetch_assoc($ans);
echo first_post['topic_title'].'-'.$first_post['username'].'<br /> '.$first_post['topic_text'].' <hr />';
//Outputs something like "Who would win in a fight... - Bob123 <br /> Superman or Batman?
mysql_free_result($ans);
//Gotten the first post and everything else, now to see the comments.

$sql = "SELECT p.*,u.username FROM posts p, users u WHERE u.user_id=p.user_id AND p.topic_id = ".$_GET['t'];
$ans = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($ans)){

   echo $result['username'].' <br />'.$result['post_text'].'<hr />';

}
//This will output something like Sneezerella <br /> Batman <hr /> Bob123 <br /> Superman <hr /> ....[etc]....

mysql_free_result($ans)
```

There will also come a time where you have to use LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and/or INNER JOIN statements. From what I can explain, here are the differences

1. Inner Join - This is the other way to write the SELECT t.*,u.username FROM topics t, users u WHERE t.user_id = u.user_id. The Syntax here is SELECT t.*,u.usernmae FROM topics t INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = t.topic_id. This method looks for 1 row in the added table, "users" in this case. If it does not find a corresponding row, it will return a null value. I.E. if I have user_id = 1 on the topic post, and the user_id is actually 2, this won't return anything.
2. Left Join - Adds on the data from the right table onto the data selected from the left. [This Article on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) gives a quick break down of it. Basically it will ALWAYS select from the original table, and will return NULL for any other results. The syntax is the same as INNER JOIN, just replace INNER with LEFT. so we would get SELECT t.* FROM topics t LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id=t.user_id. In our example above I said that if you had a mismatch in user_id's from the two tables, nothing would be returned. Not so for LEFT JOIN. Instead if the same circumstances were true you would receive results as though you had just selected from the topics table, along with a column named username that had results of NULL.
3. Right Join - Same functionality as LEFT JOIN. I can't say I've ever used this very much as I prefer to use LEFT JOIN. Basically A RIGHT JOIN query would look like SELECT t.*, u.username FROM topics t RIGHT JOIN users u ON u.user_id=t.user_id. This would give all Usernames with NULL for all the columns in topics. This could perhaps be better explained through [This Article](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) on W3Schools.

Comment: Hey, sorry for not being more clear, but I am so unsure myself and not always sure what I have to include! =)  Ok, Table B is the user database table, table C is the topics database table and Table A is where they are 'joined' in a sense. Both A & B have a column for UserID and both A & C have a column for Topic. Is that better or should I try to explain differently?

Comment: I am now fetching Table A to display on my page in a HTML table. In that table I include the 'details'-button, when clicked another table should appear. Based on the topic number in the row of the clicked button, the table displayed should contain only relevant information from database table B. So if I click the 'details'-button, it should display all users who selected that specific topic. Does that make any sense?

Comment: I am thinking I need something like this, but I do not know how to formulate: If(isset('details-btn')){ fetch data from table A where topic in table A=topic of details-btn; Then echo out in a table.

Comment: So, to make sure I understand this correctly, Table B is the user database, Table A is the topics database, and Table C is? If that is the case then I think I understand whats going on, let me type something out and see if that is what you're referring to.

Comment: I suppose my issue is that I am not understanding the use of Table C. If you want to see who's been interacting with Table A, then a simple query on Table A with a WHERE clause would do? Or are you trying to get the other details from the topic?